# use title content as existing field

Tags: nodes

I have created content type with multiple entries some of them have term reference / autocomplete.

Why cant i do that to the title for the content type? 
Is there a way I can make that happen?

Also why can't I use the title in other content types?

Attached image with title .[image]

Comment: If I am sure, you want to display `title` with fields in node view page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you can't use the title as you wish, is because it's not a `Field`, but a `Property`.

Unfortunately I can't find a meaningful explanation of the difference between the two at this time, so no link, sorry.

If it helps in any way, you can create your own title field, which will then behave more like you expect. Of course, you'll then have two "titles", so this will various annoying side effects.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, maybe this will clear it up. I would like to use autocomplete on the title with data from the title field to suggest existing names.

Comment: Since its not a field is there any other way ? other than using duplicate title ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following what it is you want to do.

Comment: This is the actual question i wanted to ask - http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/97844/add-autocomplete-to-content-type-title-node?noredirect=1#comment114511_97844